# Rest response being captured as a map instead of custom object

Tags: java, jackson

I am getting the following from a rest call.

```
[
    {
        "IMAGE": "",
        "DESCRIPTION": "",
        "HEADER": ""
    }
]
```

I am using these values to construct another response to the calling client.

In that response, I want it to be in lower case as follows.

```
[
    {
        "image": "",
        "description": "",
        "header": ""
    }
]
```

This is what I am doing currently to convert.

```
// a large json response received from the rest call. 
Benefit benefits = // rest call 

//this is above block of response where the keys are upper case currently. 
benefits.get(FURTHER_DATA); // type is Object

// casting to my custom object.
List<FurtherData> data = (List<FurtherData>) benefits.get(FURTHER_DATA);
```

Works fine but the key is still upper case.

When I see it in debug format, I am expecting it to be a list of my FurtherData object.

Instead it is actually showing up as a LinkedHashMap. How? Am so confused. Please help. Thanks.

This is the custom FurtherData object. Another weird thing going on here. I can comment out all the fields here. Still works. Again... how?

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class FurtherData {

    @JsonProperty("IMAGE")
    private String image;

    @JsonProperty("DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @JsonProperty("HEADER")
    private String header;
}
```

P.S: To note, this is not myself missing out some additional logic elsewhere.

>It's all happening in following line. If I comment it out, the response doesn't have the above block of data as expected.

```
List<FurtherData> data = (List<FurtherData>) benefits.get(FURTHER_DATA);
```

This is Benefit object.

```
// other fields
private List<FurtherInfo> furtherInfo;
```

Comment: How does benefits object look like?

Comment: @code_mechanic Updated the question with the benefit. Is just a list of FurtherInfo objects.

Comment: Benefit object is the deserialized response which you are getting from REST call, so it can given some insights.

Comment: Is benefits a map? because if your json is deserialized to this object, you should get the value as `benefits.getFurtherInfo()` . Which library you are using to deserialize the json to object?

Comment: @code_mechanic Jackson. Benefit is within another Object within another parent Object which is just a raw Map that captures the REST call. Am guessing issue is coming from parent being an Object.

Comment: Deserializing into object should not be an issue but it looks like your are mapping to a map at each level. You should add minimal structure of json to the question and the deserialization part of that json.